# Framework JEST (if et else)

Tags: javascript

I'm new to the JEST framework.
I looked everywhere.
I couldn't find anything so maybe you could put me on the line.

I can't test my if and my else regarding the verification of files in the form of JPG JPEG and PNG.

It's my first time here. I'm not looking for an answer, but maybe you could put me on the voice?

Thanking you in advance.
I have to test test a site with the JEST framework and I admit that I get lost in all this.
If anyone has an idea I'm interested, thanking you very much.
I don't see how to put my if and my else in a JEST test and I searched for hours

If you also have good courses, whether on Udemy or other platforms, I am interested

I have this piece of code:

````
    const file = this.document.querySelector(`input[data-testid="file"]`).files[0]
    const filePath = e.target.value.split(/\\/g)
    const fileName = filePath[filePath.length - 1]
    const formData = new FormData()
    const regex = /[^.]+$/; // add a regex to target everything after the dot in the image url
    const ext = fileName.match(regex) // match url with regex
    const email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).email
    formData. append('file', file)
    formData.append('email', email)
    console.log(ext[0] === 'jpg')
    // we add an if to include only the jpg jpeg and png formats
    if (['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'].includes(ext[0])) {
      this.store
        .bills()
        .create({
          data: formData,
          headers: {
            noContentType: true
          }
        })
        .then(({ fileUrl, key }) => {
          console.log(fileUrl)
          this.billId = key
          this.fileUrl = fileUrl
          this.fileName = fileName
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
    } else {
      // otherwise we reset the default value of the input file to prevent the submit
      this.document.querySelector(`input[data-testid="file"]`).value = ""
      window.alert("Please choose a file in jpg, jpeg, or png format")
    }
  }```
````